# Brown representability

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

[Here](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Erosicky/papers/brown4.pdf) on the page 2, I cannot find the **definitions**
of $[\operatorname{BRM}]$ and $[\operatorname{BRM}_\lambda]$.

Are they in the present paper ? I've also looked at the references at the end but couldn't find nothing helpful.

I understand from the paper some equivalents of these conditions but not the definitions.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by John Palmiery I've looked up [11] but still haven't caught the right meaning:

they say
the category $\cal T$ satisfies
[BRM]
if every n.t. $\mathbf{y} X\to \mathbf{y}X'$ is induced by a map
$X\to X'$. My problem is twofold, what is $\mathbf y$ and in what sense
induced is meant here.

Comment: The paper says "[BRM] (see [11])" and indeed [BRM] is defined in citation [11]. I don't see [BRM$_{\lambda}$] there, though.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that $\mathbf{y}$ stands for "Yoneda".

As given in [11] (Christensen-Keller-Neeman, "Failure of Brown Representability in Derived Categories", https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001056), for an object $X$ in the category $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathbf{y} X$ is the functor $\mathcal{T}(-, X)$ but restricted to the category of compact objects of $\mathcal{T}$. Given a map $X \to X'$, there is an induced natural transformation $\mathbf{y}X \to \mathbf{y}X'$; the requirement for [BRM] is that every natural transformation arises in this way.

Edit: given $f: X \to X'$, we get a natural transformation $\mathbf{y}X \to \mathbf{y} X'$ as follows: $g \in \mathcal{T}(A, X)$ gets sent to $f \circ g \in \mathcal{T}(A, X')$.

Comment: My question was **how** the n.t. is induced, can you provide me with details ?

Comment: @user122424 See my edit.